# How to use grep only to extract html tags in bash

Tags: html, linux, bash, tags, grep

So I have this code

`<span class="cur_wind">Sunrise <b>7:33 a.m.</b> <br />`

and I wanted to use grep to extract the sunrise time and the sunset time in this. How am i supposed to do that? I only want to use grep as i am unfamiliar with awk and sed and the others. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) really isn't the way to go here, but something primitive like below might work if you don't have any extra time operators.

```
grep -oP "(Sunrise|Sunset|\d+:\d+ (a.m|p.m))"
```

Sample output

```
> cat file
<td valign="top"><span class="cur_wind">Sunrise <b>7:33 a.m.</b> <br />
            Sunset&nbsp; <b>7:17 p.m.</b></span></td>
> grep -oP "(Sunrise|Sunset|\d+:\d+ (a.m|p.m))" file 
Sunrise
7:33 a.m
Sunset
7:17 p.m
```

Alternatively, something like this would probably get rid of more error cases

```
grep -oP "(Sunrise(.*)\d+:\d+ (a.m|p.m))|(Sunset(.*)\d+:\d+ (a.m|p.m))" file 
Sunrise <b>7:33 a.m
Sunset&nbsp; <b>7:17 p.m
```

And you can pipe to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) again to remove the tag characters.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `awk` to this:

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/, " ");$1=$1}1' file
Sunrise 7:33 a.m.
Sunset&nbsp; 7:17 p.m.
```